# Javascript : return object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to return object from function but it returns nothing any idea?

```
var todo = [{
    id: 'a01',
    titre: 'Citation',
    message: 'Vous êtes de ceux-là ? Ca tombe bien, je lai été moi aussi !',
    completed: false
}];

getById: function(todoId) {
    for (var i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
        if (todo[i].id == todoId) {
            return todo;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are returning the full array

Comment: probably you want to return todo[i]

Comment: use `return todo[i];`

Comment: what value did you passed to `getById` method?

Answer (score 2):

return the array element instead of the complete array:

```
getById: function(todoId){
    for(var i=0;i<todo.length;i++){
        //console.log(todo[i].id == todoId);
        if(todo[i].id == todoId){
            return todo[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me why u use todo[i] with indice ?

Comment: maybe the result will be clearer for you if you use `console.debug(todo);console.debug(todo[i]);` and check out the console output (hit F12 and find Console)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
var todo=[{
    id:'a01',
    titre:'Citation',
    message:'Vous êtes de ceux-là ? Ca tombe bien, je lai été moi aussi !',
    completed:false
}];

var getById = function(todoId){
    for(var i=0;i<todo.length;i++){
        //console.log(todo[i].id == todoId);
        if(todo[i].id == todoId){
            return todo[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be return todo[i]; instead of return todo[0];

Comment: Yes, I changed it. @SirajulHaq

Comment: Edited to fix the index. You can run this code in your console followed by getById('a01').